# JPA(Hibernate) Map String to postgres XML datatype

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, wildfly

I'm trying to get the following setup to work:
Wildfly 8.1.0 (comes with Hibernate as JPA implementation)
Postgres 9.3 database

I want to map a Java String to a colum of postgres' xml-type, but i get the error thet the column is of type "xml" while the expression is of type varchar.

Most of the (maybe) solutions i found where database specific java classes, hibernate specific workarounds or just unanswered questions on Stackoverflow.

I want to use the defined JPA-Methods to be able to switch to Mysql or SQLServer at will, even replace Widlfly+hibernate with glassfish or tomcat+openJPA without touching the code.

Tweaking something in the Database however would be fine.

I of course already did some research and found this post:
http://www.pateldenish.com/2013/05/inserting-json-data-into-postgres-using-jdbc-driver.html

so i tried adding implicit casts for text and varchar:

```
create cast (varchar as xml) without function as implicit;
create cast (text as xml) without function as implicit;
```

but postgres just says that these casts already exist. I verified this by inserting random Strings into the xml column, which worked fine.

The Exception still occurs.

thanks in advance for hints and directions,

BillDoor

UPDATE:

I use postgres 9.3.1102.jdbc41

the statements hibernate issues:

```
[PreparedStatement] setLong(3, 20)
[PreparedStatement] setNull(2, -3)
[PreparedStatement] setNull(1, 12)
[Connection] prepareStatement(insert into testTable (xml, stuff, id) values (?, ?, ?))
```

fyi: stuff and xml are nullable, ID is primaryKey and the 20 is retrieved from a sequence correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After recent discussion on pgsql-hackers I've found out that there's an easier way to deal with this. In your JDBC URL, or in the properties map passed to the driver at connect-time, add:

```
stringtype=unspecified
```

This will cause PgJDBC to report values assigned with `setString(...)` as being of `unknown` type to PostgreSQL, which will then infer that since the destination field is `xml`, the string should be treated as being of type `xml`.

Comment: changed the connectionURL to: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDb?stringtype=unspecified - the error remains the same, do i need to put the property somewhere else?

Comment: @billdoor Can you extract the underlying SQL query from the logs? (You might need to change settings).

Comment: @billdoor What PgJDBC version are you using?

Comment: updated both answers in my question, thanks for your effort by the way